# Stabilizer subgroups - proof verification

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a problem that I would like help on. I'm preparing for an exam, and I have provided my work below.

**Problem statement:** Let $G$ act on $X$, and suppose $x,y\in X$ are in the same orbit for this action. How are the stabilizer subgroups $G_x$ and $G_y$ related?

**My attempt:** $G_x = G_y = \{g \in G: gx=x\} = \{g \in G: gy=y\} \forall x,y \in X,    \forall g \in G$.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $G_{gx}=g G_x g^{-1}$ for any $g\in G,x\in X$.

The inclusion $G_{gx}\supseteq g G_x g^{-1}$ can be shown by applying some $ghg^{-1}$ to $gx$ for any $h\in G_x$

For the other direction show that $g^{-1}kg\cdot x=x$ for any $k\in G_{gx}$.

Comment: What does $G_{gx}$ stand for?

Comment: The stabilizer of $gx$. If $y$ is in the orbit of $x$, then $y=gx$ for some $g$.